# Applying A List of Functions to a Number

Tags: scheme, racket

I understand that functions in Scheme/Racket like map, foldr, and filter, can do wonderful things like apply a function to a list of elements.

Is it possible to apply a list of functions to a single element?

I would like to generate the values produced by each of the functions, then find their maximum. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first part, this procedure will apply a list of functions to a single argument, assuming that all the functions receive only one argument. A list with the results is returned

```
(define (apply-function-list flist element)
  (map (lambda (f)
         (f element))
       flist))
```

For the second part, finding the maximum in the list is simple enough. For example, if the element is `2` and the list of functions is `(list sin cos sqr sqrt)`:

```
(apply max
 (apply-function-list (list sin cos sqr sqrt) 2))
```

**EDIT :**

Here's another possible solution, without using `apply` and in a single procedure:

```
(define (max-list-function flist element)
  (foldr max -inf.0
         (map (lambda (f) (f element))
              flist)))
```

Use it like this:

```
(max-list-function (list sin cos sqr sqrt) 2)
```

Comment: Ah thank you sir. That would do it. I haven't learnt apply though, so I'll be doing more research on my part. Thanks!

Comment: Apply is useful for calling a function with a list of arguments. So, for instance, (apply + (list 3 4 5)) produces 12.  It is often the case that apply can be replaced with a use of fold; in this case, foldr1 or foldl1. This is useful in languages that don't have 'apply', since foldl1 and foldr1 are "regular" functions that can be defined in any language (well, just about any language).

Comment: @John What is foldl1 and foldr1?  I don't see reference to them on docs.racket-lang... is it anything like srfi/1's reduce?

Comment: Ah.. I see. Does apply have a big resemblance to map? It seems that they function similarly.

Comment: Could something similar be used for lists instead of a number?

Answer (score 2):

Another clever way to apply one function after another is to fold with compose like so:

```
(define functions (list add1 abs list))
((foldl compose1 values functions) -5) 
;which reduces to (list (abs (add1 (values -5)))) 
;which reduces to '(4)
```

Comment: Awesome! I couldn't get my own using APPLY to work, but this works great AND it's built in. Thanks!