# Implementing apply-all function in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function `apply-all` that is passed a list of functions and a number, and produces a list of the values of the functions when applied to that number

For example,

```
(apply-all (list sqrt square cube) 4) => (2 16 64))
```

assuming that all functions have been previously defined

I know how to write each function separately and how that would work but I am a little confused about how to go about doing this one and processing what functions are passed

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797991/applying-a-list-of-functions-to-a-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to traverse the function list and, for each function in turn, apply it to the number parameter. The easiest way to do this is by using the `map` procedure:

```
(define (apply-all flist num)
  (map (lambda (f) (f num))
       flist))

(apply-all (list sqrt square cube) 4)
=> '(2 16 64)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it that I like, using `for/list`:

```
(define (apply-all fs n)
  (for/list ([f fs])
     (f n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (apply-all fs n)
  (cond
    ((null? fs) fs)
     (else (cons ((car fs) n) (apply-all ??? ???)))))
```

Is probably what you were supposed to write, if this was an assignment.